# Windows 10 won't boot after externalizing HDD

Tags: windows-10, boot, external-hard-drive

I have an old laptop (Acer Aspire 5749) that I wanted to upgrade from an HDD to an SSD. Because I have plenty stuff where I will have to find my license keys or installation media, I wanted to use the old windows installation for those software, which I haven't migrated to the SSD already.

I installed Windows 10 on the SSD and put the HDD into an USB to SATA enclosure. The SSD works fine but I cannot boot form the previously internal HDD any more.

I get the sad BSOD with the error: `INACCESSIBLE BOOT DEVICE`

Is there a way to make the laptop start form the externalized HDD? Otherwise I will have to swap it back into my laptop and postpone the SSD upgrade until I find all the things I need to install.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Windows was never designed to boot from usb unless it is a Windows To Go installation.

Answer (score 1):

You should put the SSD in the enclosure and boot from the HDD,
then use one of the following free tools to clone the HDD to the SSD:

- [EaseUS Todo Backup Free](https://www.easeus.com/backup-utility/migrate-windows-10-to-ssd.html)
- [AOMEI Backupper Standard](https://www.aomeitech.com/articles/ssd-cloning-freeware-4125.html)

Once you have cloned the HDD to the SDD, put the SDD into the computer and boot.

Comment: Doesn't answer kwasmich's question.  He doesn't want to clone the HDD to an SSD. He is happy with it on the HDD. HE wants to know why the HDD which works fine when plugged into a SATA port fails when plugged into a USB via a SATA-USB adapter.   Cloning isn't a solution because the cloned drive will never work on the USB which is where kwasmich and I need it to work.

Comment: @WallyZ: This answer is from 2018, but what you say is curious. IMO "upgrade from an HDD to an SSD" does not mean moving Windows to USB and booting from it. As said in a comment by Moab, this requires Windows To Go.